# I need to know what to do with all these wires

Tags: electrical

my outlet kept shocking me when I tryd plugging anything into it so I took it apart now I have 2 red 2 black 2 almond and 1copper wire HELP

Comment: Call an electrician.

Comment: I usually change the outlets and other things myself but have no need for all these caps on unnecessary wires

Comment: Just put it back together the way it was.

Comment: Take a pic of what you have.

Comment: If you took it apart and you can't put it together correctly, you probably shouldn't be taking it apart, and you should probably call someone competent to put it back together. It's not rocket science, but it does require a level of understanding you don't appear to display in asking the question or your approach to it. And it can kill you directly or by burning your house down. You don't say where it is, but a kitchen seems like an excellent bet, as that's where MWBCs are commonly seen, and no wires are "extra" if that's what it is, which it probably is.

Comment: I would ask for you to post a photo, but if you had taken a photo before disconnecting everything you wouldn't have this problem. On the old receptacles are there metal straps between the wire connection screws? Please also specify the outlet type and your location if not in the US.

Answer (score 1):

This remains a terribly low-quality vague question, but going with the most likely common answer for 120/240V USA/Canada style wiring, it's got all the signs of being a multi-wire branch circuit (though testing is required to verify that that is what it is, and to sort out whatever the root cause of the original problem is.)

- A multi-wire branch circuit (MWBC) is commonly used to provide the
  code-required two 20 amp circuits to a kitchen countertop area,
  though they can be used in other places. Your wires are red, white
  (faceplates come in almond - wires are white, though they may turn a
  bit off-white with time), and black, plus a bare ground wire. The
  circuit (if an MWBC) will be fed from two side-by side breakers -
  they should be tied together or a dual-pole breaker under current
  code, but some older installs will have non-tied breakers.

  The tab on the hot side of the outlet will be broken, with red
  connecting to one half, black to the other. There should be 240V
  between red and black in this arrangement. Neutral is the white wire;
  there should be be 120V between the white wire and the red wire, and 120V between the white wire and the black wire. There should be
  no voltage between white and ground, and there should be low
  resistance between white and ground.

  One red wire will connect to the breaker, one to the next outlet in
  line. One white wire will connect to the neutral in the service box,
  one to the next outlet in line. one black wire will connect to the
  breaker, one to the next outlet in line. There are no "extra" wires.
- The other common possibility for this number and color of wires in an
  outlet is if the outlet is half-switched (in which case normally the
  red wire is the switched half.) In that case there is usually no
  voltage between black and red (when the switch is on), and still 120V
  between white and red (when the switch is on), and 120V between white
  and black.

If "the outlet was shocking you" then you may have an open ground, an open neutral or both - tracking that down and fixing it properly is one reason to call in an electrician here.

Answer (score -4):

The copper wire should be the ground especially if it is bare. Either the red or the black wire would be the hot wire (one with the electric current). The best way to know for sure is to use a circuit tester and touch one lead to the red or black and the the other to the copper wire. Dont touch the wires with your fingers. Which ever shows current is the hot wire. If both shows current you have a 3 wire circuit and no neutral, if that is the case then the copper wire is taking the place of the neutral and the wireing is really old and the system should be inspected by an electircian. I worked on electric for about 25 years and a condition such as you have should be worked on by qualified people so that no one gets hurt.

Comment: You seem to have missed the "two almond" (presumably aged white) wires, and you fail to understand or explain (well, I suppose you can't explain what you don't understand)  a multi-wire branch circuit (which this most likely is based on the color and number of wires.) They are neither "really old", nor lacking a neutral. BUt you do need to understand what you are working on.

Comment: I didn't miss anything, I was only replying to the post. Will not reply again.